# Nomad parameterized batch jobs autoscaling strategy to create instance only when client resources are fully utilized

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, nomad

I am new to Nomad, I am looking for a way to run N parameterized jobs in parallel on a single instance and when the resources of the instance are fully utilized I want to create a new instance.
Is there a way to do this in Nomad using the Autoscaling strategy? I am deploying Nomad on AWS and using Prometheus as the APM.

I have tried this tutorial
https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/tutorials/autoscaler/horizontal-cluster-scaling-on-demand-batch
However it created a new instance every time a job is dispatched.
Instead I want to run say 10 jobs in parallel and when the resources on the client are fully utilized I want to create a new instance